# Is there a way to download only specified chunk range in bittorrent clients?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

I know I can choose not to download specific files in torrent clients, but that is not enough precision in some cases. Sometimes I know roughly the time range within a movie where I wanna look up a specific scene, but I can't select downloaded chunks with more precision than the whole file (in uTorrent, at least). Are there any other bittorrent clients that allow this, or is there some other way that I can do this (plugin, perhaps)?

Comment: No, it is not possible in any torrent client that I know of. Closest functionality to the one you have requested is "Download in sequential order" in qBittorrent. This will start downloading chunks of the file sequencially starting from the beginning. This is good entough for previewing, but not for skipping to particular scene. There is some info you might find interesting here: http://superuser.com/q/415359/281154

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with Deluge if you use this plugin: http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Plugins/Pieces

Answer (score 2):

In [BiglyBT](https://www.biglybt.com/) you can do that in the *show details* -> *pieces* -> *piece map* view

[image]